# ROS: Publish topic without 3 second latching

Tags: ros, robotics, mavlink

As a premise I must say I am very inexperienced with ROS.

I am trying to publish several ros messages but for every publish that I make I get the "publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds", which looks like it is blocking for 3 seconds.

I'll leave you with an example of how I am publishing one single message:

```
rostopic pub -1 /heifu0/mavros/adsb/send mavros_msgs/ADSBVehicle "header: // then the rest of the message
```

I've also tried to use the following argument: -r 10, which sets the message frequency to 10Hz (which it does indeed) but only for the first message I.e. it keeps re-sending the first message 10 times a second.

Basically i want to publish a message without latching, if possible, so i can publish multiple messages a second. I have a constant stream of messages coming and i need to publish them all as fast as i can.

Comment: For me, the question is quite unclear. What do you mean with "publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds"? Could you please try to describe whats the current behaviour and whats the behaviour you want to achiev in a clear / understandable way?

Comment: Hi. Sorry if i wasn't clear. I'll describe the whole problem.
I have a ADS-B anthena that is dumping data to my pc. With that data i am generating mavros_msg/ADSBVehicle messages. I want to then publish those messages. Every message i publish (sucessfully) i get a message in terminal saying  "publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds". What i want is to avoid this message latching so i can publish messages without having to wait 3 seconds after every publish. Is that clear/ does that make sense? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're trying to do this via CLI? It seems to me this should just be a node.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Where are you defining a delay of 3 seconds? You should try to give us more context / code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue is that `rostopic` CLI tools are really meant to be helpers for debugging/testing. It has certain limitations that you're seeing now. Unfortunately, you cannot remove that latching for 3 seconds message, even for 1-shot publications. Instead this is a job for an actual ROS node. It can be done in a couple of lines of Python like so:

```
import rospy
from mavros_msgs.msg import ADSBVehicle

class MyNode:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('my_relay_node')
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10.0) #10Hz

        self.status_pub = rospy.Publisher('/heifu0/mavros/adsb/send', ADSBVehicle, queue_size=10)

    def check_and_send(self):
        #Check for some condition here
        if some_condition:
            output_msg = ADSBVehicle()
            #Fill in message fields here
            self.status_pub.publish(output_msg)

    def run_node(self):
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.check_and_send()
            self.rate.sleep() #Run at 10Hz

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = myNode()
    node.run_node()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth answer. As I mentioned I'm really new to ros and had no ideia the CLI tools were limited compared to creating actual nodes. I will consider that the answer correct since it does answer my question. I just have one other question if you don't mind. I have a program (a c program) that dumps data (which is the adsb vehicle data). How can I publish to that node that external program? Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you’re asking. However, as per SO guidelines I think it’s recommended you create a new question for this.

Comment: Will do so. Thank you for your help.